# Getting parameters in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to get a particular parameter with Zend Framework 2. For example,

```
// set the form to be used in the update templates view
    $form = new EmailTemplateForm();

    // gets the form method request (usually post)
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // check to see if the request was a POST form request
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        // good to go
        // filter the form values now
        $email = new EmailTemplates();

        $form->setInputFilter($email->getInputFilter());

        // set the form data to hold all the values supplied by the form
        // via $request->getPost()
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        // now we will see if the form is valid
        // we check if it is valid by the email form class we created
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // it is valid
            // pass the form to data to the filter class via exchangeArray()
            $email->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            $tpl_id = !empty($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') : null;

            if ($this->getEmailTemplatesService()->modifyEmailTemplate($email, $tpl_id) === true) {
                // the updated email template was inserted into the database successfully
                // redirect to email template view
                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/admin/email-template');
            } else {
                // error occured..
                // the error is logged automatically
                // redirect to email template view
                return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/admin/email-template/' . $tpl_id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Would $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') return the id number from the page url? I have the route set up to be in the format of:

```
'route'    => '/admin[/][:action][/:id]',
```

So if a form was submitted (via POST) and the corresponding url was /admin/edit-template/3 would $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') contain 3?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, if post url have same parameter it will work, why you asking instead of trying?

Comment: couldn't test it right now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take param from post maybe it's better to use:
    `$this->params()->fromPost('param_name');`

If you want from route:
    `$this->params()->fromRoute('id');`

You can create  with 'id' input name, and you can use id from route.